# C++ Pass a argument through a class with array index?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

```
class cat
{public:
  void dog(int ID, char *value) // int ID I'd like to be the index array it was called from?
  {
    debug(ID, value);
  }
}

cat cats[18];

cats[1].dog("value second arg, first arg auto filled from index array");
```

I want something similar to this.

```
   include <vector>

class CatArray;

class Cat {
    // This line means that the CatArray class can 
    // access the private members of this class.
    friend class CatArray;

    private:
        static int ID;

    public:
        void dog(const char* value) {
            // Use ID here any way you want.
        }
};

int Cat::ID = 0;

class CatArray {
    private:
        std::vector<Cat> cats;
    public:
        explicit CatArray(unsigned int size) : cats(size) {}

        Cat& operator [](unsigned int index) {
            Cat::ID = index;
            return cats[index];
        }
};
```

But a little different. There are 18 Clients in a game and i need to basically do this.  for eg, "Client 4 Chooses an option and the option gets called through the array index and than that way client 4 will call the function with the function holding the index 4"

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: I cannot really make any sense out of this; the cat & dog analogy is confusing (it seems you are really using "cat" and "dog" as meaningless words like "foo" and "bar"). But I have the feeling that you should just use `std::map`. And even if a map is not the right thing to use, raw arrays and character pointers are certainly the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Then `cats[1]` is not really a `Cat` object but a `CatWithIndex` object:

```
class Cat {
public:
  void dog(size_t index,const char* value);
};

class CatWithIndex {
  size_t index_;
  const Cat &cat_;
public:
  CatWithIndex(size_t index, const Cat &cat): index_(index), cat_(cat) {}

  void dog(const char* value) {
    cat_.dog(index_,value);
  }
};

class CatArray {
private:
    std::vector<Cat> cats;
public:
    Cat& operator [](unsigned int index) {
        Cat::ID = index;
        return CatWithIndex(index,cats[index]);
    }
};
```

Comment: i wanna make it to where say 2 players are in the game right? well i wanna make it to where if 1 of them calls say iprintin("Hello");//just prints text on the screen. it will call for only them, not everybody else

Comment: so what would i pass as the client parameter? would it be index_?

Comment: class Clients{
private:
 byte ClientID;
public:
 Clients(byte Client) { ClientID = Client; }

 uint Entity(){return (0x82F03600 + (ClientID *0x280));}
 bool isAlive(){return *(PINT)((int)Entity() + 0x19F) ? true : false; }
};

This is my current class that isn't just doing it ya know? I was basically looking for a 'upgrade' on it lol

Comment: Sorry cannot understand your comments. I'm not a native english speaker.